# Is the site about physical modelling or computer modelling?

Tags: discussion

"Is the site about physical modelling or computer modelling?"

The question says it all!

Comment: What do you understand under 'physical modeling'? I think the a51 question have quite well established that this site is about computational modeling, so I guess we only needed to decide on the first one.

Comment: I would say the site is about Materials Modeling. What I understand, and the way I learned materials theory is that whether you work with Density Functional theory or kp perturbation theory, you're going to deal with code to some extent. I know "hard core" physicists who have never run a simulation themselves but are now collaborating with computational folk to do better science. They need to understand how computational modeling works. Likewise, computational folk need to know how to extract info needed for effective models. Use HPC or a laptop and pencil, it's materials modeling.